# app build on OSX can't find config file

Tags: c++, xml, macos, qt

I am developing apps in C++ for distribution on different OSs. A lot of them have some xml config files that get read on startup, ie 'my_app_config.cfg'.

In the code, I use Qt's file dialog objects to access the file and I use boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp to do the xml parsing. Pretty straight forward stuff, really simple xml files.

On Windows and linux, this works fine, but when I make an app on Mac, it always throws me the 'Cannot read config file:' message that I wrote in my code if the file can't be opened.

What's weird is that this only happens when I call my `load_config()` function on startup -- i.e in the canonical Qt constructor, `MainWindow::MainWindow(...)`. I can load the config file after startup with my menu item which calls the same `load_config()` function.

I thought that maybe I should put the config file in the app's Contents/MacOS folder where the actual binary is, but this doesn't work either (plus I don't want config files invisible to my users).

Things like this keep me awake at night.

Comment: Why did this get voted down? This is a good question.

Answer (score 3):

Recently in Mac Qt applications, the default working directory is not intuitive.  It is the root of the harddrive.

You can verify this with this in your program:

```
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#static-public-members

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#currentPath

This is a typical fix I put at the top of my Mac/OSX programs:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    // Doesn't default to its app directory.  Goes to root for some reason with Mavericks
    QDir::setCurrent(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    qDebug() << "Working Directory:" << QDir::currentPath();
#endif
```

Now you should be able to copy your config stuff into your `Contents/MacOS` folder and it should find it at runtime.

Also be sure to look into using `QSettings` and `QJson`.  `QSettings` is really convienent for storing settings and configurations.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html#overview

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @phyatt. I will try this. BTW, did you vote my question down? Seems unlikely since you took the time to post this very clear and thorough answer. I thought it was a good question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it.  I suppose the downvoter may have thought the question was unclear or had a lot of non-essential info.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  I got the gist of the question fast enough and put in my two cents.

Comment: Just to confirm, I implemented phyatt's fix and it did the trick. Thanks again.